Raspberry Pi Pico finally entered bootloader mode...now it's not recognised by Thonny and won't flash
I flashed the script below to a working pi pico. (I'm running windows 11 on my laptop). The script ran fine, but then it stopped being recognised by Thonny. I couldn't get it to enter bootloader (by holding down the bootsel button) and change USB drivers using Windows Device Manager and Zadig failed. The script continued to run fine on the Pi Pico; I just couldn't connect it to Thonny any more. Device Manager showed a USB driver with a problem; I was unable to resolve this using the USB driver approaches described above. At this point, my second Pi Pico connected to Thonny with no issues.
The next day, for some reason, I managed to get it into the bootloader. I used flash_nuke.uf2 to wipe the board contents, but then couldn't get MicroPython onto the board using Thonny's inbuilt flash tool (it just timed out, saying 'could not find port').
Weirdly, Thonny will not recognise my second Pico either now. No COM ports appear in Thonny when either board is connected. I've tried changing USB cables and USB ports with no success, but I don't have another laptop to try. Does anyone know what I'm missing here?
import network
import machine
import socket

# Define the onboard LED pin
led2 = machine.Pin("LED", machine.Pin.OUT)
led = machine.Pin(16, machine.Pin.OUT)

def connect_to_network(ssid, password):
  wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
  wlan.active(True)
  wlan.connect(ssid, password)

  # Wait for connection
  max_wait = 150
  while max_wait > 0:
    if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status() >= 3:
      break
    max_wait -= 1
    print('waiting for connection...')
    led.value(1)
    led2.value(1)  # Turn LED on using value() method
    time.sleep(0.25)
    led.value(0)
    led2.value(0)  # Turn LED off using value() method
    time.sleep(0.25)

  # Handle connection error
  if wlan.status() != 3:
    counter = 0
    while counter < 150:
      led2.value(1)
      time.sleep(1)
      led2.value(0)
      time.sleep(1)
      counter += 1
    raise RuntimeError('network connection failed')
  else:
    print('connected')
    led2.value(1)
    status = wlan.ifconfig()
    print('ip = ' + status[0])
    return status[0]  # Return the IP address of the Pico

def start_socket_server(ip):
  addr = socket.getaddrinfo(ip, 80)[0][-1]
  s = socket.socket()
  s.bind(addr)
  s.listen(1)

  print('listening on', addr)

  while True:
    cl, addr = s.accept()
    print('client connected from', addr)

    request = cl.recv(1024)
    request = str(request)
    print('Request:', request)

    if 'GET /ledon' in request:
      led2.value(1)
    elif 'GET /ledoff' in request:
      led2.value(0)

    response = """HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
<head>
  <title>LED Control</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>LED Control</h1>
  <p>LED is now {}</p>
  <p><a href="/ledon">Turn LED ON</a></p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p><a href="/ledoff">Turn LED OFF</a></p>
</body>
</html>
""".format('ON' if led2.value() else 'OFF')

    cl.send(response)
    cl.close()

# Connect to the laptop's Wi-Fi network (replace with your actual credentials)

# Connect to the laptop's Wi-Fi network
ip_address = connect_to_network('network_name', 'password')

# Start the socket server
start_socket_server(ip_address)

#remember, ip address for control is http://192.168.4.1

